# Submiting a form in another domain and getting result displayed in my page using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I understand that the question is little bit vague. Still I am tempted to ask this. I will give one working example and would like to know, how I can use this in my project. There is a site called http://erail.in .In this, if I want to get the details of a train or PNR, just enter in the form and submit. This (I assume) opens the train or PNR search page of Indian Railways (probably in the background) and get details pertaining to the value given by me and display the result in the page in which I am.
Similar way I have a form in my page which has one input box for entering TLD No.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="/DatePicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

TLD No.<input type="text" id="tip"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon submitting this form , I need a jQuery script which opens another search  page in another server and submit the form in that page get the result from that page to my script.  The search page in that server is like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>INDIVIDUAL ALL REPORT</title>
<base target="_self">
</head>

<body >
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="../dbms/allindvres.asp" target="I1">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" bordercolor="#669999" width="100%" id="AutoNumber1" >
    <tr>
      <th width="100%" colspan="4" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cc6600; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-TRANSFORM: uppercase">individual data in one click</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle" ><font size=4>TLD No &nbsp;<input name="TLDNO" size="10"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle" ><font size=4>CC No &nbsp;<input name="CCNO" size="10"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle"><font size=4>or Name &nbsp;<input name="name" size="30"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle">
        <p align="center"><a href="../DBMS/allindvres.asp" target="bottom"><input type="submit" value="Get Life Dose" name="B1"></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<iframe name="I1" width="100%" height="500" src="../DBMS/allindvres.asp" marginwidth="10" marginheight="5">
Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe></p></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Once the form is submitted, the result is displayed in the iframe above. The resulting html will look like this

```
<html>

<head>
<body>


<h3 align = 'center'><font color="red">
                OTHER STATION
                </h3>               

<table border="2" align = 'center' cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="80%" id="AutoNumber2">
 <tr>
    <TD WIDTH = 85% align = 'left' colspan='3'>
    <table border="0" align = 'center' cellpadding="0"  width =100%>
    <tr>
        <td>CC NO:</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <Td>SECTION: </td>
        <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>NAME: </td>
        <td>XXXX </td>
        <Td>CATEGORY: </td>
        <td>XX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FATHER'S NAME:</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <Td>EMP NO: </td>
        <td>XXXXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BIRTH PLACE </td>
        <td>XXXXX</td>
        <td>CC NO:</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>STATE</td>
        <td>XXXXX</td>
        <td>DATE OF BIRTH</td>
        <td>3thMay1968</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>QUALIFICATION: </td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>DESIGNATION: </td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to get values in  second  of second  from the above table and display it in my page.  How can I accomplish this?

If I am using the action="http://anotherserver/dbms/allindvres.asp" in the form above, After submitting I can get the result in an I frame in my page. But I do not want to use the default form submit method which refreshes the page. That is why I use jQuery. Any work around?

Comment: It's seems you feel comfortable working with jQuery and are biased towards thinking the jQuery way to solve a problem. In this case, browser js isn't the right tool for the job. Cross domain requests, scraping and iframe DOM events are full of restrictions. I advise working with a backend server to do the scraping part. Node's Request and Cheerio modules could do the job. Besides, Cheerio uses jQuery syntax.

Comment: If I am using the action="http://anotherserver/dbms/allindvres.asp" in the form above, After submitting I can get the result in an I frame in my page. But I do not want to use the default form submit method which refreshes the page. That is why I use jQuery. Any work around?